# Dual citizenship and different legal gender?

Tags: dual-citizenship, passport, transgender

Is there any information on any prevailing or official policy on people with dual citizenship, where the legal gender is different in the two countries? Is there any information available on what the policy is in different countries?

The reason I'm asking is that my wife is a Thai citizen, but will live in Sweden and eventually become a Swedish citizen. She was born male, but lives as a woman and has gone through gender reassignment surgery (at a certified clinic, with all paperwork in order). In Thailand it is not possible to change one's legal gender (ie in official records and documents, like passport), but it is possible to do that in Sweden.

If someone has information regarding the policy in these specific countries, that is of course very welcome. But I am also interested in general information about the policy in other countries. I have not found much online, and nothing of any official standpoint or law text.

And official policies aside, can you think of any strong arguments against doing this, ie having dual citizenship and different legal gender? In what situations could this become a problem? And is there anything one could do to mitigate some of these problems? One problem I can think of is when traveling, as [this article](https://www.vice.com/en_us/article/paeydg/an-airline-refused-to-let-a-trans-woman-board-her-flight) focus on.

Comment: Did your wife also have a name change? Or does she intend to have one?
In that case, she may not only have a mismatch of gender but also a mismatch of names which may be even worse. If your wife had (or will have) a name change, you should really familiarize yourself with how Thailand handles a limping use of names.

Comment: Rather ironic that the country where more SRSs are performed than in any other still has no avenue for changing one's legal gender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wife wants Swedish citizenship with female gender. Having "female gender" will be much much more important than having the same gender in two passports.

Most countries want to see *one* passport. They will check one passport, and only one passport, and check if there is anything suspicious or unusual about the passport. There's nothing unusual about your wife having a Swedish + female passport. It would be unusual for your female looking wife to have a Thai + male passport. Or a Swedish + male passport. So she can show her Swedish passport and should have no problems.

(In the situation described in the linked article, your wife would have been fine with her Swedish + female passport, but not with Thai + male, and quite possibly not with two passports).

Comment: Thank you for reassuring me that this most likely won't cause more problems in the future. We actually filed for registration for her a few days ago, and specifically requesting her to get the official female gender, and at least the clerk handling the application didn't say anything about it not being allowed. So now we wait and see.